# VS extensions crashing at once

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I am experiencing a bunch of extensions/features crushing at once with the very same error in VS. Restarting the ide helps for a while, but sometimes the issue reappears instantly after the restart. Sometimes it is not appearing for a longer while. It is totally random how many and when they crash.

I have also upgraded to the latest VS, with no positive effect.

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.6.5
> VisualStudio.17.Release/17.6.5+33829.357 Microsoft .NET Framework
> Version 4.8.04084
>
> Installed Version: Community
>
> Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA707 Microsoft Visual C++ 2022
>
> ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0 This package contains services used
> by Data Lake tools
>
> ASA Service Provider   1.0
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.6.326.62524 ASP.NET and Web Tools
>
> Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.6.326.62524 Azure App Service
> Tools v3.0.0
>
> Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0 Microsoft Azure
> Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio
>
> Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.6.326.62524 Azure Functions
> and Web Jobs Tools
>
> Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0 Microsoft
> Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio
>
> C# Tools   4.6.0-3.23259.8+c3cc1d0ceeab1a65da0217e403851a1e8a30086a C#
> components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and
> settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.10 Provides common services for use by Azure
> Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> Cookiecutter   17.0.23087.1 Provides tools for finding, instantiating
> and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.
>
> Dotfuscator Community Edition   6.5.3+7f0b0a9d18 PreEmptive Protection
>
> - Dotfuscator CE
>
> GitHub Copilot   1.94.0.0 (v1.94.0.0@6586dd2df) GitHub Copilot is an
> AI pair programmer that helps you write code faster and with less
> work.
>
> GitHub Copilot Agent   1.94.220 (v1.94.0)
>
> Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0 Language
> service for Hive query
>
> Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
> Language service for Azure Stream Analytics
>
> Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9 Support for Azure Cloud
> Services projects
>
> Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting the
> Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines
>
> NuGet Package Manager   6.6.0 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
> For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/
>
> Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio   17.6.33520.00 Microsoft
> Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio
>
> Python - Django support   17.0.23087.1 Provides templates and
> integration for the Django web framework.
>
> Python - Profiling support   17.0.23087.1 Profiling support for Python
> projects.
>
> Python with Pylance   17.0.23087.1 Provides IntelliSense, projects,
> templates, debugging, interactive windows, and other support for
> Python developers.
>
> Razor (ASP.NET Core)
> 17.6.0.2327201+a6a61fdfa748eaa65aab53dab583276e26af4a3e Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   17.6.13.0 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> Syntax Visualizer   1.0 An extension for visualizing Roslyn
> SyntaxTrees.
>
> Test Adapter for Boost.Test   1.0 Enables Visual Studio's testing
> tools with unit tests written for Boost.Test.  The use terms and Third
> Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.
>
> Test Adapter for Google Test   1.0 Enables Visual Studio's testing
> tools with unit tests written for Google Test.  The use terms and
> Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation
> directory.
>
> ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0 Hosting json editor into a tool window
>
> TypeScript Tools   17.0.20329.2001 TypeScript Tools for Microsoft
> Visual Studio
>
> Visual Basic Tools
> 4.6.0-3.23259.8+c3cc1d0ceeab1a65da0217e403851a1e8a30086a Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and
> settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
>
> Visual F# Tools
> 17.6.0-beta.23174.5+0207bea1afae48d9351ac26fb51afc8260de0a97 Microsoft Visual F# Tools
>
> Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2 AI-assisted development for Visual
> Studio.
>
> Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0 This package contains the necessary
> Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.

[image]
[image]